# Android Facebook SDK FriendPickerFragment how to filter friend's list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using the FriendPickerFragment provided by Facebook SDK for Android, i'm lacking a very important feature - the ability to filter the ListView that shows all my friends.

Its pretty amazing its not a default option there - because usually the average Facebook user has more than 300 friends, so to have all of them in a list without being able to search\filter them is a bit weird.

Am I missing something? maybe there is some sort of property I need to set that i didn't?

or the only option should be customizing the SDK internally?

Answer (score 0):

The FriendPickerFragment inherits from the PickerFragment (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/PickerFragment/) and there's a setFilter(GraphObjectFilter) method that does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: yeah i saw it in the code, the problem is that i will need to change the SDK code in order to use it (adding EditText view for filtering, wiring it to code, etc...). I kind of wanted to avoid that.. I hoped to find something more native... they have a filter box in any other UI (Web, IOS, etc..). don't know why they didn't add it here

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, I think the new permissions are the issue. I was only able to show a list of friends who APPROVED AND LOGGED INTO THE APP. They want you to use /me/invitable_friends now and it's not clear how that will integrate into FriendPickerFragment.          https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids